# Parsing AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, lint

I would like to just say thank you for anyone that helps. But I am not able to parse my AJAX response properly:

My AJAX Request:

```
$('#sumbit_LoggingGet').on 'click', ->
username = $('#login_username').val()
password = $('#login_password').val()
mac_id = $('#login_LoggingGetmac').val()
id = $('#login_LoggingGetid').val()

$.ajax
  type: "GET"
  url: start_url + mac_id + "/log-config/" + id
  dataType: "json"
  crossDomain: true
  cache: false
  beforeSend: beforeSend(username, password)

  success: (data) ->
    console.dir data
    successMessage("""<h1>Logging Get Results</h1>""")
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_username')
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_password')
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_LoggingGetmac')
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_LoggingGetid')

    for key,value of data
      $('#data-results').append """<br>
      <h3><span style="color: #0000CD;"> #{key}</span></h3>
      <br><h4> #{value} #{value.id}</h4><br>"""
```

**Results:**

id

logger1 undefined

points

[object Object] undefined

reports

[object Object] undefined

capacity

16070400000 undefined

**True Results:**

```
{
"id": "logger1",
"points": [
    {
        "id": "00000000/pulse_1",
        "interval": 300000,
        "enabled": true
    }
],
"reports": [
    {
        "collector": "collector1@talkrnd.enernoc.net",
        "interval": 300000,
        "enabled": true
    }
],
"capacity": 16070400000
}
```

Comment: @MikeW I think triple quotes are a CoffeeScript thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED answer based on comments**

`JSON.stringify` is what you are looking for. stringify takes a parameter for pretty-printing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON

```
$.ajax
  type: "GET"
  url: start_url + mac_id + "/log-config/" + id
  dataType: "json"
  crossDomain: true
  cache: false
  beforeSend: beforeSend(username, password)

  success: (data) ->
    console.dir data
    successMessage("""<h1>Logging Get Results</h1>""")
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_username')
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_password')
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_LoggingGetmac')
    clearColor(areaText = '#header_LoggingGetid')
    $('#data-results').html JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2)
```

Comment: Use `#{value[0]?.id}` rather than `#{value.id}`

Comment: Thank You for that! But my results are now like this
http://pastebin.com/hv3GHXEt

Comment: Are you still outputting `#{value}`?

Comment: For the input data you provided in the question, that looks right to me. What is your expected output?

Comment: I am trying to get it to match the True Results in the original post.

Comment: So you want to display `JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: I am guessing, how can I do that? , if you do not mind showing me with my code example?

Comment: `$('#data-results').append JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: Yep just did that all are printed now but like this. 
http://pastebin.com/Dseje9mN

Comment: but how can I make it readable and "clean" with a separation for each category:  

1.id
2.points
3.reports
4.capacity

Comment: Great! But it is still is in the odd unreadable format as in the last pastebin? Any fixes for that, good sir?

Comment: Sorry, that's deeper than I wanted to get in this question

Answer (score 1):

It is working correctly. Your `undefineds` are accurate, since none of your values are `objects` with an `id` property. All of your values are either `arrays` or `strings`.

Answer (score -1):

The `append` method in jQuery does not do template tag replacement in the current context. It just takes a string of HTML, another jQuery collection or a DOM node.

You'll want to do something like:

```
var html = "...".replace(/#\{(\w+)\}/g, function(match, tag) {
    return data[tag] || "";
});

$(...).append(html);
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with this syntax, at least run the coffeescript through a javascript converter.

Comment: It's to bad you think this way, my answer is the correct one.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, your answer maybe correct somewhere but not in this code block.